# Handle windows authentication login popups Cancel click

Tags: asp.net, windows, authentication, loginview

I have simple web application called App that is secured with Windows Authentication. I have set identity impersonate to true in web.config. There is only one page (Default.aspx) in App directory. When user enters the site ex.: http://localhost/App the login window pops up. When user clicks Cancel, IIS redirects to page with an error 401.2. I want to redirect to http://localhost/App/app_start/login.aspx. App_start is an aplication that is secured with Forms Authentication. I tried to handle programmatically the redirection by adding Application_EndRequest method in Global.asax file. But when user clicks Cancel the Application_EndRequest is not being fired. When user successfully logs in the method is being fired. Is there any way to handle error 401.2 programmatically or maybe in a different way?

Application_EndRequest code:

if (Response.StatusCode == 401)

{

```
 Response.Clear();

 Response.Write("You don't have access to content.");
```

}

The web.config file of App application:

Thanks for help.

Sincerely,

Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the 401.2 error in IIS to be redirected to a URL instead of a file.  If you do this just set the 401.2 redirect to your other web application and that should work.

Right Click on the site in iis, properties, custom errors.